# Can't install anything with software center

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, dpkg

Every time I open Software center I get this message:

```
New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. 
Do you want to repair this problem now?
```

I click repair and get this error message:

Package operation failed 
The installation or removal of a software package failed

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...  
(Reading database ... 5%  
(Reading database ... 10%  
...
(Reading database ... 100%  
(Reading database ... 224334 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../libflite1_1.4-release-8_i386.deb ...  
Unpacking libflite1:i386 (1.4-release-8) ...  
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-8_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1.4' to '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1.4.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-8_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386 depends on libflite1; however:
  Package libflite1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I want to install Playonlinux to install Itunes to use with my new Ipod.

So this is what I'm getting with the `sudo apt-get -f install` command:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
  compiz-plugins-main fonts-takao-pgothic fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tlwg-garuda  
  fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-norasi  
  fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-typewriter  
  fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-waree  
  gnome-dictionary gnome-search-tool kde-l10n-engb libquvi-scripts libquvi7  
  libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk  
  printer-driver-hpijs printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-pnm2ppa  
  printer-driver-pxljr  
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  libflite1  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  libflite1  
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 354 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/12.7 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 20.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
(Reading database ... 224334 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../libflite1_1.4-release-8_i386.deb ...  
Unpacking libflite1:i386 (1.4-release-8) ...  
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt  
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-8_i386.deb (--unpack):  
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1.4' to '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1.4.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream  
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...  
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic  
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20130906ubuntu2) ...  
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.  
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libflite1_1.4-release-8_i386.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get this at the very end after `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`

```
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.3) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libflite1 but it is not going to be installed
 python-wxgtk2.8 : Depends: python-wxversion (>= 2.6.3.2.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxgtk-media2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Execute this command at once (without brackets) : (sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a)

Comment: still getting the same thing :/

Comment: Execute this command : sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install playonlinux curl python-wxgtk2.8 cabextract p7zip-full

Comment: You do one thing, enable remote desktop on your system and i will control it remotely. Check this site http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ubuntu-remote-desktop-sharing/ . Just enable Remote Desktop , search Remote Desktop in Dash and give me your ip address (by executing hostname -I )

Comment: I think I'm done for tonight I've been trying to do this all day, I do have google hangouts(Lee-Ann Pipp e-mail: shyfroggy15@aol.com) and skype(shyfroggy)

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal by pressing Crtl+Alt+T.

Then execute these command in terminal one by one :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E0F72778C4676186
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux curl python-wxgtk2.8 cabextract p7zip-full
```

Comment: I tried this and it still isn't working, I got another error after just the first command, I edited my question above including the error