# Conky won't show weather information

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, themes, indicator, conky

I am using the [Harmattan](http://zagortenay333.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Harmattan-426662366) theme.

this is how it looks:
*(On Xubuntu 14.04 LTS release with XFCE 4.12)*
[image]

**For some reason the weather info won't show up.**

```
ashesh-pc1@A1315IN:~$ 
Conky: desktop window (1200003) is subwindow of root window (7c)
Conky: window type - normal
Conky: drawing to created window (0x2600001)
Conky: drawing to double buffer
sh: 1: curl: not found
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/ashesh-pc1/.harmattan-assets/photos/smallest/.png’: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/ashesh-pc1/.harmattan-assets/icons/small-#dcdcdc/.png’: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/ashesh-pc1/.harmattan-assets/icons/small-#dcdcdc/.png’: No such file or directory
grep: /home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.xml: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/ashesh-pc1/.harmattan-assets/icons/small-#dcdcdc/.png’: No such file or directory
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather-1.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather-1.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather-1.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather-1.png'
Conky: Unable to load image '/home/ashesh-pc1/.cache/weather.png'
```

I already have `conky` installed, on trying to install `curl`, I get the following messages:

```
ashesh-pc1@A1315IN:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
[sudo] password for ashesh-pc1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.3) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have also tried other theme but they produce similar issues.

**How can i fix this?**

Comment: I followed the "README" file include inside the zip

Comment: yes I did, using http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/592859/186134

Comment: I have given up on the weather information, issue is defiantly because of curl. Manually getting the weather.xml file helped, thank you for your assistance. :-)

Comment: that's fine, thanks for the accept :) I'm happy to continue helping you with the curl issue if that link doesn't work.

Comment: the last time i ran those commands i messed up, seems like too much trouble to go through plus I have a work around for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get curl on my system, the probable fixes that I got were too much to go through so I finally **settled on using `wget` instead of `curl`**.

The program `curl` in this case, basically get the weather information from yahoo servers and saves it to your disk, this can also be done using `wget`.

**WORKAROUND**

**1.** Open the `/home/yourusername/.conkyrc` file using some text editor like **gedit** or **mousepad**.

**2.** Look for the line similar to:

`${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295411&u=c" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}`

and add this line above it:

`${execi 300 wget "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295411&u=c" --output-document=.cache/weather.xml}`

So, it looks something like:

```
${execi 300 wget "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295411&u=c" --output-document=.cache/weather.xml}
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295411&u=c" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}
```

**3.** Save the file, restart Conky `pkill conky && conky`

---

Note that "2295411" here is the WOEID and varies depending on the location, you can find yours here at [Yahoo WOEID Lookup](http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/)

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem even though following all the steps.

Answer (score 3):

> You may also need to grab Curl if it’s not already installed.

to install, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

> Once you have fully downloaded the `.zip` you need to extract it, and move the files inside to your home folder (`/home/USERNAME`).

You may have completed the following, if not then keep reading.

> That’s all that's needed to install the Conky theme. But you'll need to edit the weather location to match that of your own:
>
> - Go to weather.yahoo.com
> - Search for your location in the weather search box (underneath forecast)
> - Copy the numerical string in the URL
> - Open .conkyrc in your Home folder
> - Find the number: ‘2294941’
> - Replace it with the numerical string you copied from the Yahoo! Weather URL Save

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/google-now-themed-conky-for-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: this gives me the error **"libcurl3 (=7.35.0-1ubuntu2.3) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed"**

Comment: @Ashesh please could you edit in the whole error to your question?

Comment: question description updated, for the time being I have manually placed the `weather.xml` file in the `.cache` folder, not sure if it fixes the problem permanently.